# What are this properties in libjpeg and in libpng?

Tags: c++, libpng, libjpeg

I'm actually using the libjpeg to read and save JPEG images.
So first what are the possibilities of pixel size (`info.output_components;`) ?
What are the possibilities of color space (`info.out_color_space;`) ?
And can a JPEG image have an alpha channel ?

I'm using the libpng too.
So first what is the bit depth (`png_get_bit_depth(png, info);`) ?
And what is the color type (`png_get_color_type(png, info);`) ?

Thanks !

Comment: [`libpng` manual](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.4.0-manual.pdf) and the [Wikipedia PNG article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) have more information about bit depth (number of bits per channel), and color type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So first what are the possibilities of pixel size (info.output_components;) ?

From the [doc](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/master/libjpeg.txt)

> `output_components` is 1 (a colormap index) when quantizing colors; otherwise it
> equals `out_color_components`.  It is the number of JSAMPLE values that will be
> emitted per pixel in the output arrays.

```
  int out_color_components;     /* # of color components in out_color_space */
  int output_components;        /* # of color components returned */
  /* output_components is 1 (a colormap index) when quantizing colors;
   * otherwise it equals out_color_components.
```

> What are the possibilities of color space (`info.out_color_space;`) ?

From the [source](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/6d8caa9f88184ad1698e91c94b37acb9506dacf0/jpeglib.h#L217)

```
  JCS_UNKNOWN,            /* error/unspecified */
  JCS_GRAYSCALE,          /* monochrome */
  JCS_RGB,                /* red/green/blue as specified by the RGB_RED,
                             RGB_GREEN, RGB_BLUE, and RGB_PIXELSIZE macros */
  JCS_YCbCr,              /* Y/Cb/Cr (also known as YUV) */
  JCS_CMYK,               /* C/M/Y/K */
  JCS_YCCK,               /* Y/Cb/Cr/K */
  JCS_EXT_RGB,            /* red/green/blue */
  JCS_EXT_RGBX,           /* red/green/blue/x */
  JCS_EXT_BGR,            /* blue/green/red */
  JCS_EXT_BGRX,           /* blue/green/red/x */
  JCS_EXT_XBGR,           /* x/blue/green/red */
  JCS_EXT_XRGB,           /* x/red/green/blue */
  /* When out_color_space it set to JCS_EXT_RGBX, JCS_EXT_BGRX, JCS_EXT_XBGR,
     or JCS_EXT_XRGB during decompression, the X byte is undefined, and in
     order to ensure the best performance, libjpeg-turbo can set that byte to
     whatever value it wishes.  Use the following colorspace constants to
     ensure that the X byte is set to 0xFF, so that it can be interpreted as an
     opaque alpha channel. */
  JCS_EXT_RGBA,           /* red/green/blue/alpha */
  JCS_EXT_BGRA,           /* blue/green/red/alpha */
  JCS_EXT_ABGR,           /* alpha/blue/green/red */
  JCS_EXT_ARGB,           /* alpha/red/green/blue */
  JCS_RGB565              /* 5-bit red/6-bit green/5-bit blue */
```

> And can a JPEG image have an alpha channel ?

As you can see from the source code above, libjpeg-turbo does support alpha channel for jpegs.

---

> So first what is the bit depth (`png_get_bit_depth(png, info);`) ?

Simply put, number of bits used to represent each pixel in an image. The higher the bit depth, the more colors each pixel can contain.

From the [PNG Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html):

> Color type is a single-byte integer that describes the interpretation of the image data. Color type codes represent sums of the following values: 1 (palette used), 2 (color used), and 4 (alpha channel used). Valid values are 0, 2, 3, 4, and 6.
>
> ```
>   Color    Allowed    Interpretation
>   Type    Bit Depths
>   
>   0       1,2,4,8,16  Each pixel is a grayscale sample.
>   
>   2       8,16        Each pixel is an R,G,B triple.
>   
>   3       1,2,4,8     Each pixel is a palette index;
>                       a PLTE chunk must appear.
>   
>   4       8,16        Each pixel is a grayscale sample,
>                       followed by an alpha sample.
>   
>   6       8,16        Each pixel is an R,G,B triple,
>                       followed by an alpha sample.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer ! Is there a way to get the pixel size in the libpng ?

Comment: Is there a color space in libjpeg like this : `monochrome/alpha` ?

Comment: @PacCol doesn't seem like it.

Comment: What is the X value in `JCS_EXT_RGBX` ?

Comment: X means, that it has  an alpha channel, but it is ignored, and is always set to 255.

Comment: What is the difference between `JCS_RGB` and `JCS_EXT_RGB` ?

Comment: They are colorspace extensions. Read more about it here: https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/master/README.md#colorspace-extensions